# Как из одного Activity инициировать изменения в другом?

Tags: android, activity

Приведите пример кода, в котором обработчик события в `Button` одного `Activity` изменял бы `TextView` в другом `Activity`.

Вот мой обработчик:

```
String data = "This is the best day";
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("man", data.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }    
}}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### В Main2Activity.class:

```
    TextView txt_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTxtView);
    txt_1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("man"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Во втором `activity`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getStringExtra("man");
```